# Get both inner html and current element html using jSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following same code....

```
<a id="rowID5" class="title-link">
 <div id="rowData">
  <div>Some text here</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

Now i HAVE to do a select off the "a" element using the following code...

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlData);
Elements row = doc.select("a.title-link");
```

Now when I do the following...

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++){
 String foo = row.get(i).html();
 break; //I break here only for Testing Purposes there will be more rows eventually
}
```

The problem is of course is when "foo" is returned it's equal to...

```
 <div id="rowData">
  <div>Some text </div>
 </div>
```

I need "foo" to equal the original which is..

```
<a id="rowID5" class="title-link">
 <div id="rowData">
  <div>Some text here</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

The reason why I'm doing all of this is because I do a select on the document to return the inner html of the element. My code then extracts the data from within the element and does things (where foo string is created) then I need to take the full html (including the A tag element and it's children) and set it equal to "foo" as the output.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: I tried editing it. I'm not sure how much more elaborate I can be lol. I need the the output string to be exactly the same as the html originally is when it's found by doing a doc.select

Comment: there is also an outerHtml() method

Comment: Yea but doesn't that get ALL outer html including everything else surrounding it?

Comment: Why don't you try it...

Comment: @tachyonflux you should post your comment as answer. @eqiz that's what I understood, but I thought that something escapes me since it can be found so easily just by checking the methods of `Element` class.

Comment: i honestly didn't think anything of it and the reason behind that is because when I've done outerhtml before it gave me EVERYTHING. However, being the idiot and over thinking things as I sometimes do, i didn't think that since its doing the doc.select that thats the ONLY html that exists then that's the only thing that could be returned. Oh well at least i got my question answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Node.outerHtml()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#outerHtml()) does what you are looking for.